# Связал firebase с android studio, но как указать свой уникальный ID

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Есть

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

 databaseSpele =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Spele2").child(...);
```

В место child(ветку), нужно чтоб вводился email который указываешь при вводе данных. Но не принмает ни EditText, ни ID-полей, ни переменные. Как это сделать?

```
String id = databaseSpele.push().getKey();
```

Насколько известно что то в этом коде нужно прописывать?

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя  использовать email как id.
Точка(.) - недопустимый символ. См [правила](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits)

Вот похожий вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41713039/can-we-have-email-id-as-key-in-firebase-database
и
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41372563/swift-firebase-must-be-a-non-empty-string-and-not-contain-or

Не нужно использовать email как id, у каждого юзера есть уникальный [uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) - вот его и используй

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
...
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Spele2").child(uid);
```